# Failed to create menus when installing Anaconda3

Tags: python, menu

I'm trying to install Anakonda3 on Windows 7 32-bit and get an issue: Failed to create menus.
In Details I see:

> Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI32722\python37.dll'.
>
> LoadLibrary: Не найдена указанная процедура.

I'm trying to keep PATH variable empty and start installation under Administration mode, but nothing helps.

Many thanks for help!

Comment: I think Windows 7 is 64bit?

Comment: No, Windows 7 32-bit

Comment: Did you download the x86 version of Anaconda or changed any of the initial configuration from the installer?

Comment: I did't change anything. Just download x86 installer and start installation.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in a following way. I am working in virtual machines, so I create new virtual machine with Windows 7 x64 and install Anakonda3-x64 into it. And it installed successfully.